# What is the use of Redux-Router in addition to reac-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

guys. When I go through the documentation of redux-router, I just cannot understand why do we need it?

Here is what the documentation is trying to explain:

> React Router is a fantastic routing library, but one downside is that
>   it abstracts away a very crucial piece of application state — the
>   current route! This abstraction is super useful for route matching and
>   rendering, but the API for interacting with the router to 1) trigger
>   transitions and 2) react to state changes within the component
>   lifecycle leaves something to be desired.
>
> It turns out we already solved these problems with Flux (and Redux):
>   We use action creators to trigger state changes, and we use
>   higher-order components to subscribe to state changes.
>
> This library allows you to keep your router state inside your Redux
>   store. So getting the current pathname, query, and params is as easy
>   as selecting any other part of your application state.

As far as I can understand, it is trying to say redux router can keep router state inside redux store so that we can get route info more conveniently.

But within react-router, I can also easily do it. 
Like path="messages/:id", I can use this.props.params.id to get the params.

Can someone explain in what scenario redux-router bring its benefit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redux (and in general, the flux pattern) is all about having the entire application state stored in one central place. This has the benefit of easier debugging and makes it easier to implement certain features.

If you've ever used the redux-devtools in a react app with react-router, you'll notice that its only of limited use, because you can't replay the entire lifecycle of the application. When the user changes routes, that's not recorded in the redux store. Redux Router keeps the route state in the store.

You could use this for debugging, you could serialise the entire store history and log it elsewhere to replay user sessions. You could hook into it to implement full undo, or log analytics events.

Comment: Thanks Josh for your reply. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

[redux-simple-router](https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router) is a library which could help you understand how to use react router in a redux application.

It is a very simple library stores the URL in redux state and keeps it in sync with any react-router changes.

**redux-simple-router** compared to *redux-router* is:

- Much smaller and simpler. You don't need to learn another library on top of everything else.
- Encourages direct access of react-router APIs. Need server-side rendering, or something else advanced? Just read react-router's docs.
- Only stores the current URL and state, whereas redux-router stores the entire location object from react-router.

Follow one of the these 2 examples to get up and running:

- [redux-simple-router-example](https://github.com/StevenIseki/redux-simple-router-example)
- [redux-frontend-boilerplate](https://github.com/tj/frontend-boilerplate)